# Fermentation seems to be stuck at 1.065

Tags: stuck-fermentation

My cider started at 1.090 and seems to have stopped at 1.065. I put it in a secondary glass carboy. Do I need more time, it has been about three weeks?

Comment: What are your raw materials, procedure and yeast?

Comment: What temp is it at?

Answer (score 3):

You moved the cider to secondary too soon. Normally you want at least 65% attenuation to have been reached. Since apple juice ferments to nearly 1.000, that would be 1.030.

Apple juice is low in nutrients, which the yeast require to metabolize sugar into alcohol and carbon dioxide. I would suggest you move the cider back into the fermentor and add fresh yeast. Also add yeast nutrient and energizer, following the manufacturer's directions.

The fermentation should kick off again with 48 hours.

Comment: Might be fine with just adding nutrient, but re-pitching yeast is more of a sure bet.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't notice any bubbles in your airlock then you should probably add new yeast.

It is a good idea to put one of those little valves on your fermentation bucket. That way you can take SG without having to risk opening the lid.